# How can I create specific 3D cylinders in r and plot them in a map?

Tags: r, dictionary, 3d

I have around 400 rows with a radius data, a latitude and a longitude. What I need to do is to create a 3D cylinder for each row, with constant height and radius = radius data; and place them in a map. I have investigated the rgl package but until now, I've not been successful. 
Could anyone give me any query about how to perform this task? any help would be most valuable.
Thanks in advance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3148.jpg)

Comment: What is the role of the latitude and the longitude? Do they give the center of the base of the cylinder? Or what?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to represent visual information in the map, not just a point with a color code, but that the radius of that cylinder also contain information. So coming back to your question, yes, the latitude and longitude should serve to correctly place each cylinder in the map; so indeed the lat and long mark the center of the base of the cylinder.

Comment: And all the cylinders are vertical ? Or you mean the base point in on a sphere, and the cylinders are orthogonal to the sphere ? (not clear what you call a "map")

Comment: Maybe you have an image showing an example of the desired output ? Something is missing in your description.

Comment: Do you mean something like that: https://i.imgur.com/tROL6jp.png ?

Comment: Yes, all the cylinders should be vertical with respect to the surface of the map. By map I mean spatial data contained in a shapefile (.shp). The idea is to give also information with the width of the cylinders (not the height which has to be constant for all them), so my interest is to play with the radius of the cylinders. I managed to create the cylinders with the function "cylinder3d" from rgl package. Now I need to "link" somehow these cylinders with a latitude and longitude coordinates and plot them in the map. they are mesh 3d objects.

Comment: I have an example in png but not sure if I can upload a picture in the forum. I can send by email if it is necessary.

Comment: You can edit your post and click on the icon to upload an image.

Comment: I am sorry @StéphaneLaurent but I don't find that icon to upload an image.

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I think now it is, I was trying to upload the image in the comments

Comment: Ok I see. But unfortunately I don't know anything about shapefiles. Do you know a R package which is able to display a 3D map from a shapefile ?